# AppMaker - Navigate to Last Page on Table

Tags: google-app-maker

Scenario:
I have a calculated SQL that returns 100 results.
Added a table (from this calculated SQL) and limited the size of the page by 25 results.
This will generate 4 pages.
Pager form AppMaker works well (navigates between pages) but i need a button that navigates directly from page 1 to the page 4.
is this possible?
Anyone got a solution for this?

Regards

Comment: The only way i have this working is if you have a concurrent count model running that returns the total number of records only. I have not started working with SQL so I don't know if SQL models already return a total record count or not.

Comment: but that will work if i know that the query returns 100 records and then i have only 25 per page.. If this numbers change, it will not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to know how many entries your table has (in your case it's seems fixed to 100, but maybe it could grow), you can still do what you want:

E.g. say your table on `YOURPAGE` depends on a datasource called `Customers`.

1. Create a new Data item called `CustomerCount`, with just one field, called `Count` (integer).
2. Its data source would be a sql query script:

`Select count(CustomerName) as Count from Customers`

3. on the page you are having the table on, add a custom property (say called 
   `Count` of type integer)
4. In the page attach event, set the property asynchronously with this custom action:

`app.datasources.CustomerCount.load(function() {
        app.pages.YOURPAGE.properties.Count = app.datasources.CustomerCount.count; 
        app.datasources.Customers.query.pageIndex = @properties.Count / 25;
        app.datasources.Customers.datasource.load();
    });`

I tried similar things successfully in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution for this:

ServerScript:

```
function CandidateCountRows() {
  var query = app.models.candidate.newQuery();
  var records = query.run();
  console.log("Number of records: " + records.length);
  return records.length;
}
```

in the button code:

```
var psize = widget.datasource.query.pageSize;
var pidx = widget.datasource.query.pageIndex;
var posicao = psize * pidx;
var nreg = posicao;

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(Xresult) {
    nreg = Xresult;  
    console.log('position: ' + posicao);
    console.log('nreg: ' + nreg);
    console.log('psize: ' + psize);
    console.log('pidx: ' + pidx);

    var i;
    for (i = pidx; i < (nreg/psize); i++) {    
      widget.datasource.nextPage();
    }
    widget.datasource.selectIndex(1);
}).CandidateCountRows();
```

This will allow to navigate to last page.

Answer (score 0):

If you know for a fact that your query always returns 100 records and that your page size will always be 25 records then the simplest approach is to make sure your button is tied to the same datasource and attach the following onClick event:

```
widget.datasource.query.pageIndex = 4;
widget.datasource.load();
```